# How to pass a variable in kusto query in a logic app?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics

I have a logic app which gets triggered by a storage Blob Created event, After initializing a variable and capturing the blob name, I want to pass that variable in a kusto query to get a user details who uploaded the blob as shown in the query below, but it doesnt return any value

```
StorageBlobLogs | where Protocol contains "sftp" and Uri contains "@{variables('Filename')}" and  OperationName contains "sftpcommit"  and TimeGenerated > ago(5m) | project RequesterObjectId
```

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are the expected results:

Firstly taken example KQL query testing in ADX:

```
Partner
| where Partner contains "Alten"
| project Partner
```

[image]

Now in Logic apps **`Design`**:

[image]

```
Partner
| where Partner contains "@{variables('var')}"
| project Partner
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

It is working fine and got correct output in both ADX and Logic apps, if you are not getting any thing then it means there is no row to return. There is no problem with a=using variables inside KQL query in Logic apps as I have got desired output.

**`Code view:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "Alten"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Run_KQL_query": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "cluster": "https://help.kusto.windows.net/",
                        "csl": "Partner| where Partner contains \"@{variables('var')}\"| project Partner",
                        "db": "FindMyPartner"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['kusto']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/ListKustoResults/false"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "kusto": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/resourceGroups/bojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/kusto",
                    "connectionName": "kusto",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/kusto"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`Note:`**

No spaces are allowed in string variable, as it might also cause the issue and once check, this will give empty in ADX also when you run because there are no rows to display, if gave correct query  it will work as mine worked.